# Existing VB6 DAO code against Access 2007 (.accdb) database?

Tags: ms-access, vb6, ms-access-2007, dao

Will existing `VB6` `DAO` code that previously was used against `Access 95/97` `.mdb` files work against `Access 2007` (`.accdb`) database files?

Is the following all that needs to be done to do a seamless migration?

```
(1) Convert databases to 2007 format 
(2) Run AccessDatabaseEngine.exe on the target machine 
(3) In VB6 Project|References,
    (a) Deselect Microsoft DAO 3.6 object library
    (b) Select Microsoft Office 12 access database engine object library
    (c) Select Microsoft Office 12 object library 
(4) no special code changes needed when setting db objects
```

Source: http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/opening-access-2007-vb6-accessdatabaseengine-exe-acedao-dll-t3534633.html

Comment: An awful lot of stuff got deprecated between '97 and 2000. I would be a little doubtful about the code, even if it seemed to work at first.

Comment: I am using VB6 against the MDB without an Access front-end, so I don't use `DoMenuItem`.  Are there any other deprecated functions/commands?

Comment: In that case you need to distinguish between MS Access, the RAD tool, and Jet/ACE the database that MS Access often uses.